# on(release) {...} or myButton.onRelease = function() {...} - action script 2 issues

Tags: actionscript-2

I am having real confusion with some flash banners I'm creating and making the button into a clickable object which opens a web page.

I have been using this code for a while below, which works...

```
on(release){
    getURL("http://www.the-dude.co.uk", "_blank");
}
```

And I placed this code on actual button within the actions panel

However I have been told the code above is very old and that I should use action script like below...

```
buttonInstance.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("http://www.the-dude.co.uk", "_blank");
}
```

So I've tried to get this method below to work but nothing happens when I click the button, and I get one error, this...

[image: Scene=Scene 1, layer=button, frame=1, Line 1 Statement must appear within on handler]

So in a nutshell I cannot get this newer code to work! Ahh

Can anyone please help me understand where I am going wrong?

I have tried placing the new code in the Scene 1 of my actions. No worky..

And I've also tried placing the code below, actually on my button within the actions panel...

```
this.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("http://www.the-dude.co.uk", "_blank");
}
```

Still not working.

My scene settings are alway this...

[image]

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the code below on the same timeline as the instance of the button (as you tried). And the instancename of the button must be "buttonInstance".

You can set the instance name in the properties panel when the button is selected.

```
buttonInstance.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("http://www.the-dude.co.uk", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is weird because I set the instance name set, but I had the code on the actual instance in actions. Now works when outside of instance. But is there not a way to do this with out setting a instance and just dropping code onto the button in actions? Thanks for you help

Comment: Adding code to instances is not a good style. Your code is more readable and easier to maintain if it is not spread over all instances, but is located on one place. If you want to have the code directly on your instances you need to use the `on(release)` syntax.

Comment: That does make sense. I used to use flash about 9 years ago and I was still in the mind set of applying actions directly to the instance. But your right, having all the code in one place is logical. Thanks