# Open a PDF file in flash CS6 with AS2

Tags: flash, pdf, actionscript-2

I need to open a PDF file in Flash CS6 without using `fscommand`. I tried some things that I find in Internet:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8fKHTwbOJ0)
[Web page](http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/95007.aspx)

I do the same that this bibliography said but doesn´t work. I do not know what I am doing wrong. This is my **Action** in the button.

```
on (release) {
 getURL("sales/brochure.pdf","_blank");
}
```

This is my **folder**

[image: My folder]

I do not want do this with `fscommand` becouse I have to open many PDF file, and for other hand I do not want to see the black window that shows with `file.bat`.

**Information Added**

The problem is that the button don´t do anything, I make what the example said but do not show (open) the PDF file. But with the `fscommand` it shows the file.

I tried to open a **html** file, but doesn´t work. Apparently, the `getURL` doesn´t work. I do not know what to do.

**2nd Information added**
I tried to make this

```
on (release) {
getURL("mailto:marite@lacetel.cu", "_self");
  }
```

and it works, open a window to write the mail, now, I do not know what doesn´t work with pdf or html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is not clear. *Does not work* **how**? You cannot click the button in question? Or script is not executed? Or window does not open? Or something else?

Comment: @Organis The problem is that the button don´t do anything, I make what the example said but do not show (open) the PDF file. But with the `fscommand` it shows the file.

Comment: Can you get **getURL** working, if you open not a PDF file, but another web page, for example? Also, do you test it in Flash or in browser? Try both, just in case.

Comment: @Organis I think **getURL** doesn´t work, I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689817/onrelease-or-mybutton-onrelease-function-action-script-2-iss) and **publish** my work but stil doesn´t work.